# How to resize imageView to always match its image background dimensions in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, setbackground

I'd like imgFirstAct imageView to resize its width exactly to the width of the background set to it, whenever the background is wider or thinner then the imageView.

Here is the imageView xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFirstAct"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgCopyBelow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:maxWidth="290dp" />
```

Here is the code:

```
private ImageView imgFirstAct;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

          imgFirstAct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFirstAct);

          imgFirstAct.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

          Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgCopyBelow.getBackground().getCurrent()).getBitmap ();

          int h = bitmap.getHeight();      

          Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 120, h);    

          Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),croppedBmp);   

          imgFirstAct.setBackground(d);  
}
```

I'm setting here an image, which is wider than the imageView, but the imageView doesn't get wider to the width of the background image.
What should I do?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add Padding in your Xml layout file to ImageView then the background will be wider by padding.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to set the image to fit within the background of the imageview, you need to set scaletype in xml as below

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Thanks, ReshmaDB. I need the imageView to fit the width of the set background image. If background image is wider than the imageView, the imageView should widen.